# Javascript this keyword return undefined

Tags: javascript

i'm trying build slideshow function with OOP literal way.

so, this is my code :

```
"use strict";

var slideshow = {

    elSet   : $(".slideshow"),
    elCount : indexCount(".dealList"),
    elWidth : width(".dealList"),
    elNo    : 1,
    next    : function() {

                if (this.elNo < this.elCount) {
                    console.log(this.elSet);
                    this.elNo += 1;
                    this.elSet.style.transform = "translateX(-" + this.elWidth * this.elNo + "px)";
                }
                else {
                    console.log(this.elSet);
                    this.elNo = 1;
                    this.elSet.style.transform = "translateX(-" + this.elWidth * this.elNo + "px)";
                }
    },
    initial : function() {

                var loop = setInterval(this.next, 5000);
    }

}

slideshow.initial();
```

the problem occure in browser console :

1. out of memory
2. console.log return undefined

it is possible the problem occure because of this keyword?

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback of the `setInterval()` when executed is bound to the global object and not your object. You can, however, bind it to your object by using this code instead:

```
initial : function() {
  var loop = setInterval(this.next.bind( this ), 5000);
}
```

- [MDN on `bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Why not use your JS dupehammer to point this to the canonical Q&A?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Usually I'm too lazy to find the canonical answer and just writing 5 lines is faster.

Comment: Haha... fair enough... I have a few bookmarks as there are [a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) [few](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) keep being asked...!

Comment: thanks Sirko for your method, i appreciate it

Comment: anyway Sirko, is there any alternative way to solve this problem, like using var that = this?

Comment: @ChingChing something like this would work also: `initial: function(){ var self = this, loop = setInterval( function(){ self.next(); }, 5000 ); }`.

Comment: thanks Sirko, i will use this method. it seems like more relevant. thanks :)